# socket stays established after closing the process of the running program

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote a python program which uses sockets, but there's one problem and the problem is that when I close the running program(from the task manager or even from the X button) the server socket stays established(still listening) and it causes problem in the next program run(because the port is taken)

if anyone could help me I will be grateful, Cheers.

Comment: Google for TCP TIME_WAIT state and SO_REUSEADDR option.

Answer (score -1):

If you open a file for writing, then kill the program, the file is still on disk.  Same with sockets (which, internally are just files)

One way to avoid this is to install a signal handler that cleans up and sockets one a kill or HUP event:

```
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
        # your sockets management code here 
        sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Press Ctrl+C')
signal.pause()
```

Comment: ' kill the program, the file is still allocated' - what whacky OS are you using?  All the non-trivial, sane ones release all non-shared process resources when a process is terminated.